# Return next customer visit date

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table with unique customers in with their last visit date. I have another historical table that contains all of their visits plus any future dates booked in. I need to be able to return the next visit date after their last visit.

Can someone help as the problem I am having is that some customers have more than one future date booked in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query which gives you the history table rows whose visit dates are more recent than the customers' last visits.

```sql
SELECT
    c.CustomerID,
    h.VisitDate
FROM
    CustomerVisits AS c
    INNER JOIN History AS h
    ON c.CustomerID = h.CustomerID
WHERE h.VisitDate > c.LastVisit;
```

Once you have that working correctly, you can use it as a subquery in a `GROUP BY` query where you retrieve the minimum visit date for each customer.

```sql
SELECT
    sub.CustomerID,
    Min(sub.VisitDate) AS next_visit
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            c.CustomerID,
            h.VisitDate
        FROM
            CustomerVisits AS c
            INNER JOIN History AS h
            ON c.CustomerID = h.CustomerID
        WHERE h.VisitDate > c.LastVisit
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something on these lines would suit:

```
SELECT cv.CustomerId, cv.LastVisit, 
      (SELECT TOP 1 h.Visitdate 
       FROM History h 
       WHERE h.Visitdate>cv.LastVisit  AND h.CustomerId = cv.CustomerId 
       ORDER BY h.VisitDate) AS NextVisit
FROM CustomerVisits cv
```

Comment: I will try this but will it work if someone has multiple future visits?

Comment: Yes, it will, note Top 1